# Reverse next functionality to create previous slide functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

I have created a very basic carousel. Currently I have used a bit of jQuery code to create the next slide functionality. Although the previous slide functionality is proving to be more tricky. The problem I think is the first slide does not have a slide before it at the start of the DOM and this is causing some confusion.

I have tried prepending the elements on page load and I have also tried prepending the items on click of the previous button.

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__item">
    test1 left
  </div>
  <div class="carousel__item carousel__item--active">
    test2 active
  </div>
  <div class="carousel__item">
    test3 right
  </div>
  <div class="carousel__item">
    test4
  </div>
  <div class="carousel__item">
    test5
  </div>
</div>
<button class="next">
  next
</button>
<button class="prev">
  prev
</button>

$('.carousel__item--active').prev().addClass('carousel__item--left');
  $('.carousel__item--active').next().addClass('carousel__item--right');

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  var activeSlide = $('.carousel__item--active');
  $('.carousel__item--left').removeClass('carousel__item--left');
  activeSlide.removeClass('carousel__item--active').addClass('carousel__item--left');
  $('.carousel__item--right').removeClass('carousel__item--right').addClass('carousel__item--active');
  $('.carousel__item--active').next().addClass('carousel__item--right');
  $('.carousel__item--active').prev().addClass('carousel__item--left');
  $('.carousel').append($('.carousel__item--left').prevAll())
})   

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  var activeSlide = $('.carousel__item--active');

  $('.carousel__item--left').removeClass('carousel__item--left').addClass('carousel__item--active');
  activeSlide.removeClass('carousel__item--active').addClass('carousel__item--left');
  $('.carousel__item--right').removeClass('carousel__item--right');
  $('.carousel__item--active').next().addClass('carousel__item--right');    
  $('.carousel__item--active').prev().addClass('carousel__item--left');
  $('.carousel').prepend($('.carousel__item--right').nextAll());
})
```

Please find a codepen example. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLLrjg?editors=1010

Comment: Are you open to a pure JavaScript approach for this?

Comment: Definitely open. I would actually prefer that although my Vanilla JS isn't the strongest but I am learning